# Using PHP in smarty template system to get SUM from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, smarty

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
   $result = mysql_query("
SELECT SUM(s.amount) 
  FROM tblaffiliatespending s
  JOIN tblaffiliatesaccounts a
    ON a.id=s.affaccid 
  JOIN tblhosting h
    ON h.id = a.relid 
  JOIN tblproducts p
    ON p.id = h.packageid 
  JOIN tblclients c
    ON c.id = h.userid 
 WHERE affiliateid = $affiliateid 
 ORDER 
    BY clearingdate DESC;
    ");
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$pendingcommissions = $data['?????????'];
$this->assign("pendingamount", $pendingcommissions);
```

What I'm not sure about is what to enter for `?????????` on the third line.  I've tried all of these things and none of them have worked:

```
$pendingcommissions = $data['SUM(tblaffiliatespending.amount)'];
$pendingcommissions = $data['SUM'];
$pendingcommissions = $data['tblaffiliatespending.amount'];
$pendingcommissions = $data['tblaffiliatespending'];
$pendingcommissions = $data['amount'];
```

Any ideas on what this needs to be changed to?

Comment: What we really like is when the whole thing's written out on one line.

Comment: What do other people do in this situation?

Comment: use SUM(s.amount) AS total and then retrieve $data['total']. also mysql_* is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You  need to give the alias for the sum of amount `SUM(s.amount) total_amount`so when you execute query and fetch the results from it you will have the sum of your amount column on `total_amount` index in resultant array and you can access it by `$data['total_amount'];`, also note using aggregate functions without grouping then will result in a single row not per group

```
SELECT SUM(s.amount) total_amount
  FROM tblaffiliatespending s
  JOIN tblaffiliatesaccounts a
    ON a.id=s.affaccid 
  JOIN tblhosting h
    ON h.id = a.relid 
  JOIN tblproducts p
    ON p.id = h.packageid 
  JOIN tblclients c
    ON c.id = h.userid 
 WHERE affiliateid = $affiliateid 
 ORDER 
    BY clearingdate DESC
```